# Adding group content to an organic group doesn't persist after submit action for hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, organic-groups, forms

In the submit handler I wrote for my implementation of hook_form_alter for a node edit form, I can successfully add a group content node to an OG using og_group() - og_is_member() returns TRUE after I call og_group(), whereas it doesn't before the call to og_group().  However, if I re-edit the node, og_is_member() no longer returns TRUE (the first time), and og_group_ref is not set as I had hoped.

Here's the code I use in my submit handler:

```
$ret = og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
dsm($ret, 'is the node a member of the group?');     // nope!
$values = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node', 
  'entity' => $node,         
);
og_group('node', $gid, $values);
$ret = og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
dsm($ret, 'is the node a member of the group now?'); // returns TRUE
```

Doing a Google search, I have found numerous instances of people saying that something very similar to the above works for them, and indeed, it does work for me - it's just that the change doesn't persist.

Anyone know why that might be the case?
TIA!
Lee

[8pm edit: add (mostly) full hook and submit handler functions, as requested.  I cut out some code handling other forms, etc.]

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_utils_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ( preg_match('/_node_form/', $form_id) && isset($form_state['field']['og_group_ref']) ) {    
    // Editing a node which has OGs: process Audience and/or Program term reference fields
    if (isset($form_state['field']['field_audience_term_']) || isset($form_state['field']['field_program_term_'])) {

      // SNIP, SNIP - manipulate taxonomy term fields on node edit forms...

      $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_node_edit_submit';
    }
  }

  // SNIP SNIP - handle other forms
}

/**
 * Process a node edit submission.
 */
function my_module_node_edit_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // init arrays
  _my_module_set_up_arrays($userOGs, $aud_ary, $pgm_ary); 
  $node = $form_state['node'];

  // for each program/audience which this user has visibility to:
  //   if program/audience is selected, select the corresponding OG for the node
  //   if program/audience is not selected, deselect the corresponding OG for the node
  foreach ($aud_ary as $key => $aud) {
    if (isset($userOGs) && in_array($aud, $userOGs)) {
      $gid = array_search($aud, $userOGs);

      if ($form['field_audience_term_'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]['#checked'] == true) {
        if (!og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node)) {
          dsm('GID to ADD for Audience '. $aud . ': ' . $gid);
          og_group('node', $gid, array('entity' => $node));
        }
      } else if (og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node)) {
        dsm('GID to DROP for Audience '. $aud . ': ' . $gid);
        og_ungroup('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
      }
    }
  }    

  foreach ($pgm_ary as $key => $pgm) {
    if (isset($userOGs) && in_array($pgm, $userOGs)) {
      $gid = array_search($pgm, $userOGs);
      if ($form['field_program_term_'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]['#checked'] == true) {
        if (!og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node)) {
          $ret = og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
          dsm($ret, 'is the node a member of the group?');        
          dsm('GID to ADD for Program '. $pgm . ': ' . $gid);
          $values = array(
            'entity_type' => 'node', 
            'entity' => $node,         
          );
          $ret = og_group('node', $gid, $values);
          $ret = og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
          dsm($ret, 'is the node a member of the group now?');
        }
      } else if (og_is_member('node', $gid, 'node', $node)) {
        dsm('GID to DROP for Program '. $pgm . ': ' . $gid);
        og_ungroup('node', $gid, 'node', $node);
      }
    }
  } 
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole functions, hook_form_alter and the submit handler?